# nav active class wont work because of image in list

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ap4QM/21/) to help see the working code.

I have been trying to achieve the sticky menu that automatically changes the color of the list item that is active. But I am now adding an image in the center as one of the list items.

Somehow it breaks the nav-active code.

I also have a code that is suppose to make the img go margin-top:-29%; when the person scrolls beyond 50 px. that doesnt show up on the jsfiddle for some reason but works.

At first I thought is the second script that is conflicting it. Then I noticed that it breaks on the third list item.

Am I doing something that breaks it? I am not quite sure why it should break the momentum of the code. Can someone please guide me??

PS: This may or may not help but I also get this error on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (index):543
(anonymous function) (index):543
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
g.handle.h
```

line 543 is from the script

```
var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
```

this error is visible irrespective of the issue I am asking help for, but doesn't usual affect my user experience.

My knowledge of javascript is basic and I cannot really understand how I am breaking the code. Please help!

EDIT :
I tried removing the image and it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/233N4/1/)

Thanks to jtorrescr I have been able to achieve what I need but now I am faced with the constant error on console

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
Z.error
bg
Z.compile
bm
h.querySelectorAll.bm
Z
p.fn.extend.find
p.fn.p.init
p
(anonymous function)
p.event.dispatch
g.handle.h

//for the js line
var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
```

Comment: Could you also add the code before adding the image to be able to compare a see your previous result?

Comment: thanks for replying. I just added it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the code asume that you are going to interact with all elements in the `<ul>`. By adding an additional element and the most important avoiding to interact with it you need to change your code. This is the solution you could work with: code http://jsfiddle.net/Ap4QM/25/

Just add an if to exclude the element you want to work with:

```
for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
                  if(aArray[i]!='index.php')
                  {
                      var theID = aArray[i];
                      var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
                      var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question

                          if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                              $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                          } else {
                              $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                          }
                  }
              }
```

to do it more flexible you could ask for the id and work with it instead of the index, so you could take it as homework

Comment: That makes sense. I tried using the edit you made within my code out here, but that somehow still ignored the last list item. However the JSFiddle code you edited is working perfectly. Any idea why I keep getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" error?? everything works as it suppose to, but it shows like a 100 errors on the console.

Comment: Yes, if you made your screen smaller (reduce the screen height by resizing your browser), you could see that it works perfect. It is due to the code you are using does not detect that the screen is over and the last div does not fire the active event. I will look at it and see if I can provide you a solution with it.

Comment: The computer I am using right now does not have a resolution to test it fine in jsfiddle, but try this, look for this code if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) replace the == with >= and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: I did try it the last one does become active. But i still get the Uncaught error... Also I have been trying to get the active to kick in about 10% before the div starts as you can see the sticky menu hides the top of the div so when it does go active the div is a under the navigation

Comment: on another site i used this same code and added +20 after `var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop()+20;// get the offset of the window from the top of page` but here it doesnt work as such

Comment: hey, I am still not able to fix the error that shows up